# Dronekit-Python over AeroCore

Tags: dronekit-python, gumstix

Teoretically, Dronekit-Python run over any hardware which supports MavLink. I tried to run dronekit over Gumstix AeroCore but I've only got reach the prompt MAV> and nothing more happens
Someone knows what's missing?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

DroneKit-Python talks MAVLink indeed but it's only being tested and developed against the [APM Flight Stack](http://ardupilot.com/), if the Gumstix AeroCore runs the APM stack then there's probably no data getting to MAVProxy.